# Is it possible to use another button to tell me the last alert?

Tags: javascript, string, button, random, alert

I am looking to have two buttons and one auto generates a random string in an alert and I want another user to be able to go and enter the code in a text box and tell them if its valid or not.

First is this possible? Second, for someone new to JavaScript is this difficult?

Here is the current code I am using right now.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function randomString() {
 var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 var string_length = 5;
 var randomstring = '';
 for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
  var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
  randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
 }
 return randomstring;
}
</script>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert(randomString());
}
</script>
```

Thanks1

Comment: another user like on a different computer? You need to explain your question properly, it is very confusing, the code you have alerts some random text.

Comment: `I want another user to be able to go and enter the code in a text box and tell them if its valid or not.` are you going to hire guys for this?

Comment: Yes, the users would be connected through same network but yes from separate computers.

Comment: You'd need a server-side language for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about that one:

----------- file: index.html -----------

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Captcha Test</title>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loadCaptcha('captcha-region')">

    <div id="captcha-region"
         style="text-indent: 10px; background: #fffccc"></div>

    <label for="captcha"> Re-type text: </label>
    <input  id="captcha" type="text" value="" />

    <input type="button" value="Submit"
           onclick="checkCaptcha('result-region')" />

    <input type="button" value="Reload"
           onclick="loadCaptcha('captcha-region')" />

    <div id="result-region"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

--------- file: test.js -----------------

```
function randomInt (range) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
}

function randomPos (s) {
    return randomInt(s.length);
}

function randomChar (s) {
    return s.charAt(randomPos(s));
}


var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function randomString () {
    var s = '',
        i = 0;

    while (i++ < 5) {
        s += randomChar(chars);
    }

    return s;
}

function htmlInsert (id, htmlData) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = htmlData;
}


var captcha;

function loadCaptcha (captchaRegion) {
    captcha = randomString();

    htmlInsert(captchaRegion, '<h1>' + captcha + '</h1>');
}

function checkCaptcha (resultRegion) {
    var okText = (captcha === document.getElementById('captcha').value)
            ? '<span style="color: yellowgreen"> ok </span>'
            : '<span style="color: orange">  not ok </span>';

    htmlInsert(resultRegion, '<h2>Typed text: ' + okText + '</h2>');
}
```

This basically is kinda captcha demo, maybe that contains some good parts..

You may want to put index.html & test.js in a directory of your liking (no local web server needed), then from inside that directory execute: "firefox index.html" and you're good to go..

What do you think?

Comment: Hi Jared, glad I could contribute, seems you want to improve your JS, and also your HTML(5) skills.  Who am I, anyway, I got skills like those, which helped you a bit from lots of sources, other (wo)men here in StackOverflow -- many thanks for that -- and via one of my central sites "coreservlets.com". And there the "Ajax % JS" section.